# Trying to create a grid of pictureboxes in an array for a board in c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, picturebox

I'm trying to make a board for a Naughts and crosses (tic tac toe) game using pictureboxes in an array and what I've come up with is this. This starts when I press a button.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
            {
                PictureBox[,] pb = new PictureBox[i, j];
                pb[i, j].Location = new Point(i * 150 + 100, j * 150 + 100);
                pb[i, j].Width = 150;
                pb[i, j].Height = 150;
                pb[i, j].Visible = true;
                pb[i, j].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                pb[i, j].BringToFront();
                this.Controls.Add(pb[i, j]);
            }
        }
```

this throws me a "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" on the line

```
pb[i, j].Location = new Point(i * 150 + 100, j * 150 + 100);
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: Isn't it just the way to set the location? it's what i came up with looking through other peoples code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not far off - you need to declare the array outside of the loop, and create a picture with each iteration  - this works (tested):

```
            PictureBox[,] pb = new PictureBox[3, 3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    pb[i,j] = new PictureBox();
                    pb[i, j].Location = new Point(i * 150 + 100, j * 150 + 100);
                    pb[i, j].Width = 150;
                    pb[i, j].Height = 150;
                    pb[i, j].Visible = true;
                    pb[i, j].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                    pb[i, j].BringToFront();
                    this.Controls.Add(pb[i, j]);
                }
            }
```

(Note the logic in the loop was wrong too, it should be < 3 not <= 3 as you're starting at 0)

Answer (score 1):

You have declared and instantiated your multidimennsional array within your `for` loops. Try the following:

```
PictureBox[,] pb = new PictureBox[3, 3];    
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{                
    for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        pb[i, j] = new PictureBox();
        pb[i, j].Location = new Point(i * 150 + 100, j * 150 + 100);
        pb[i, j].Width = 150;
        pb[i, j].Height = 150;
        pb[i, j].Visible = true;
        pb[i, j].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        pb[i, j].BringToFront();
        this.Controls.Add(pb[i, j]);                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i would say your approach of creating picture box array to create the Ticktack Toe game is wrong.Plus your code is inefficient

In your code you are repeatedly creating redundant arrays

```
PictureBox[,] pb = new PictureBox[i, j];
```

You are wasting Runtime memory here.

What i would recommend is creating a new Picturebox Class Inherited from the PictureBox class. 
Divide this rectangular area into 3X3 Matrix(in terms of dimension)
Then you need to Capture the click event and get the point

```
  private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs eM = (MouseEventArgs)e;

    //eM.X  -X Coordinate  eM.Y  -Y Coordinate 

    }
```

Using this Coordinate identify the matrix location,where the user clicked.Then redraw the whole picture-box to reflect the input made by user.
This will separate the need for maintaining a picturebox array you can concentrate just to maintain a 3X3 Integer or Boolean array(0 or 1).When a win condition occurs you just need to draw a line across the matching array entries.

Use the `Graphics.DrawLine` method to do this